# How to download with arai2c with maximum speed?

Tags: downloads, wget, download-manager, axel

I try to read manual but can't understand!

My Internet speed is very low (about 32kib/s), How can I make 32 connection with maximum speed in your experience?

Do you offer another download manager for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

uGet makes using aria2 much easier but you will not be able to get your download speed past your max internet speed regardless of the number of connections.

Comment: Thanks I try uGet and used aria2 plug-in with 16 connection but it's not use all of my bandwith, currently use xdm but it use cpu very much! because written by java

Comment: How much is uGet using on average and at peak?

Comment: My issue (because bad Internet) is that, be 0 for a few second. Is there any setting for aria2 plugin of uGet?

Comment: Yes there are Aria2 Plugin settings in the main settings under the "Plugin" section.